# api with python to give dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
apikey='*****d2deb67f650f022ae13d07*****'
first='http://api.ipstack.com/'
ip='134.201.250.155'
third='?access_key='
print(first+ip+third+apikey)
#html=urlopen(first+ip+third+apikey)
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
print(soup)
```

i had to hide the first,last 5 digits of my `apikey`,anyway this gives

```
{"ip":"134.201.250.155","type":"ipv4","continent_code":"NA","continent_name":"North America","country_code":"US","country_name":"United States","region_code":"CA","region_name":"California","city":"La Jolla","zip":"92037","latitude":32.8455,"longitude":-117.2521,"location":{"geoname_id":5363943,"capital":"Washington D.C.","languages":[{"code":"en","name":"English","native":"English"}],"country_flag":"http:\/\/assets.ipstack.com\/flags\/us.svg","country_flag_emoji":"\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8","country_flag_emoji_unicode":"U+1F1FA U+1F1F8","calling_code":"1","is_eu":false}}
```

this is giving me a soup object,what do i i need to add to get the `country_name`,`geoname_id`,`ip` in a list so i can write them later in .json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a json response

you need to parse it from json liberary

```
import json
parsed_json = json.loads(str(soup))
geoname_id = parsed_json['location']['geoname_id']
country_name = parsed_json['country_name']
ip = parsed_json['ip']
```

A better solution while dealing with REST apis that return json responses would be:

```
import requests
apikey='*****d2deb67f650f022ae13d07*****'
first='http://api.ipstack.com/'
ip='134.201.250.155'
query_string = {'access_key': apikey}
res = requests.get(first+ip+third, params=query_string)
res.raise_for_status()
ip = res.json()['ip']
```

Comment: works great man,just edit `json.loads(soup.text)` since json don't take soup objects.

Comment: i have edited it to str(soup) to exactly mimic the question print(soup)

Comment: a better solution when dealing with rest apis is to use requests liberary we res.json()

i will update the answer

Comment: thanks both works great,however the object you create `res.json()` is almost like a dictionary,how can make a for loop to iterate keys and values in it ?
it's a different question but it'd really help if you can

Comment: Just like any other dictionary for key, value in res_json.items(): print(key, value) You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start) is very helpful here - what you need to do is in there:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
print(soup.ip)
>>> "134.201.250.155"
```

Let me know if you need further help!

Comment: it returns `None`,i also tried `print(soup.select('ip'))` it returns an empty list

Comment: this is not a standard html with tags,attributes so i don't think this will work.

Comment: If it's not a standard HTML why are you using a standard HTML parser? For your problem - have you tried using `print(soup['ip'])`?

Comment: `return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'ip'`

Comment: That means it is not a dictionary - what happens if you try and iterate over it?